# Can the lunatic cultist spawn on iOS

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have the 1.3 update and it's 2019 but it still doesn't work.i have defeated the golem about 20 times now and the lunatic cultist didn't spawn. Please help!

Comment: Did you kill the cultists outside of the dungeon? That is usually how the Lunatic Cultist spawns.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if it changed in later versions, but as far as I know the iOS version never had the entire moon lord event. the final boss was Ocram, which meant no moon lord, no celestial pillars, and no lunatic cultist.

Comment: Ocram is an optional boss that becomes accessible after you beat the wall of flesh. He is also removed in 1.3.